# Spring MVC Rest vs JAX-RS

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, cxf

Is there really any benefit to using a full blown JAX-RS implementation like Apache CXF over just using Spring MVC and @RestController? The API would only take and return JSON.

Comment: An interesting question, but I don't think it's suitable for StackOverflow, based on https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask